# Error during template rendering: 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'attname'

Tags: python, django

I try to render a form in html but I raise an error and I have got no idea about its trigger.

Here is the traceback error:

```
Template error:
In template /Users/usr/Projets/your-query-master/src/core/templates/core/base.html, error at line 18
   'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'attname'
   8 : 
   9 :         <title>{% block title %} Your-Query {% endblock title %}</title>
   10 :     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
   11 :         <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "css/base.css" %}'>
   12 :         <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}'> 
   13 :        <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" %}'> 
   14 :         <link rel="stylesheet"  href='{% static "css/contest.css" %}'>
   15 : 
   16 :         <script src="{% static 'contest_bet.js' %}"></script> 
   17 :         
   18 :        <link rel="styleshee t" href="htt ps://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
   19 :        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
   20 :     </head>
   21 :     <body>
   22 :         {% include "core/navbar.html" %}
   23 :             <div class="container" style="padding-top: 80px;" >
   24 :                 {% block content %}
   25 : 
   26 :                 {% endblock content %}
   27 :             </div>
   28 :         {% include "core/footer.html" %}


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/usr/Projets/your-query-master/src/questions/views.py", line 78, in contest_bet
    return render(request, "questions/contest_bet.html", output)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 992, in render
    return render_value_in_context(output, context)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 971, in render_value_in_context
    value = str(value)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/html.py", line 373, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 33, in __str__
    return self.as_widget()
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 94, in as_widget
    value=self.value(),
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 130, in value
    return self.field.prepare_value(data)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 1241, in prepare_value
    return value.serializable_value(self.to_field_name)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 660, in serializable_value
    return getattr(self, field.attname)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /questions/1dcd2c46-8572-11ea-9a09-acde48001122/
Exception Value: 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'attname'
```

Since I have no idea from the origin of the problem. I have added the template, model, form, url and view code.

contest.html:

```
<form method="post" action="/questions/">
  {% csrf_token %}

  {form.as_ul}
   <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid1)
    top = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'role': "Top"}, related_name="top")
    top_score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    jungle = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'role': "Jungle"}, related_name="jungle" )
    jungle_score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    mid = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'role': "Mid"}, related_name="mid")
    mid_score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    adc = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'role': "ADC"}, related_name="adc")
    adc_score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    support = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'role': "Support"}, related_name="support")
    support_score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    contest = models.ForeignKey(ContestLOL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("questions:model_details", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "mymodel"
```

views.py:

```
def contest(request, slug=None):
    contest = get_object_or_404(ContestLOL, slug=slug)
    matches= Match.objects.filter(contest=contest.id)
    form = MyForm(contest.id, request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        mymodel = form.save(commit=False)
        mymodel.user = request.user
        mymodel.contest = contest
        mymodel.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Bet was saved')
        form = MyForm(contest.id)


    output = { "contest": contest,
                "form": form,
                "matches": matches
                }
    return render(request, "questions/contest.html", output)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/', contest, name='contest'),
]
```

Form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
     def __init__(self, contest_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        players= Player.objects.all()

        self.fields['top'].queryset = players.filter(role='Top')
        self.fields['jungle'].queryset = players.filter(role='Jungle')
        self.fields['mid'].queryset = players.filter(role='Mid')
        self.fields['adc'].queryset = players.filter(role='ADC')
        self.fields['support'].queryset = players.filter(role='Support')

        self.fields['top'].initial = players.filter(role='Top')[0]
        self.fields['jungle'].initial = players.filter(role='Jungle')[0]
        self.fields['mid'].initial = players.filter(role='Mid')[0]
        self.fields['adc'].initial = players.filter(role='ADC')[0]
        self.fields['support'].initial = players.filter(role='Support')[0]
    top = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Player.objects.filter(role='Top'), 
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
        empty_label=None, 
        to_field_name='top'
    )
    jungle = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Player.objects.filter(role='Jungle'), 
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
        empty_label=None, 
        to_field_name='jungle'
    )
    mid = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Player.objects.filter(role='Mid'), 
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
        empty_label=None, 
        to_field_name='mid'
    )
    adc = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Player.objects.filter(role='ADC'), 
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
        empty_label=None, 
        to_field_name='adc'
    )
    support = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Player.objects.filter(role='Support'), 
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
        empty_label=None, 
        to_field_name='supp'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('top', 'jungle', 'mid', 'adc', 'support')
```

Has someone any idea of where I should be looking to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Form(contest.id, request.POST or None)` looks wrong, unless there is an `__init__` method that you haven't shown. If the form is editing the contest, then maybe it should be `Form(instance=contest, data=request.POST or None)`.

Comment: Try to narrow down what is causing the problem, for example, you could delete all of the `fieldname = forms.ModelChoiceField()` lines and see if that solves the problem. If it does solve the problem, try adding the fields back on by one to see where the issue is.

Comment: Finally, if your variable names are really `class Form` and `class Model`, then you should rename them to avoid clashes with `forms.Form` and `models.Model`. If you are trying to hide the variable names from us, then it makes your question harder to read and might hide where the error is coming from.

Comment: I have an init method but I did not copy everything well I will add it. The variable names are not Form and Model, I will change it with MyForm and MyModel just wanted to anonymize the code. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I've already tried to delete all fieldnames and basically everything in the form and I still had the same mistake. I will still try to keep narrowing it down. If I find anything, I will post the solution here, but if someone understands it before me, I'll be glad to know.

Comment: It's important to include things like the `__init__` method otherwise you might hide the error. But if you still get the error without the fields, then remove them from your question to keep the code shorter.

Comment: `form = MyForm(contest.id, request.POST or None)` still looks wrong, even after you added the `__init__` method. Unless you change the signature of the `__init__` method, the first argument of the form is `data`. What are you trying to do with `contest.id` there?